# Exporting summary(aov.sample) to CSV in R

Tags: r, csv, output

Warning: contains self-taught R newbie.

`Summary(aov.sample)` creates a table of ANOVA results such that

```
Error: particip
      Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
Residuals 11  16.49   1.499               

Error: particip:device
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)  
device     1  14.22  14.222    3.76 0.0786 .
Residuals 11  41.61   3.783                 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Error: particip:width
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
width      1 177.35  177.35   63.64 6.71e-06 ***
Residuals 11  30.65    2.79                     
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Error: particip:length
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
length     1 183.68  183.68   115.5 3.57e-07 ***
Residuals 11  17.49    1.59                     
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Error: particip:device:width
             Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
device:width  1   0.50   0.500    0.14  0.715
Residuals    11  39.17   3.561               

Error: particip:device:length
              Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
device:length  1  1.389   1.389   0.661  0.433
Residuals     11 23.111   2.101               

Error: particip:width:length
             Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
width:length  1 276.13  276.13   120.5 2.89e-07 ***
Residuals    11  25.21    2.29                     
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Error: particip:device:width:length
                    Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
device:width:length  1  2.722   2.722   1.085   0.32
Residuals           11 27.611   2.510               

Error: Within
                           Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
group                       2    7.1   3.566   1.327  0.268
group:device                2    0.6   0.316   0.118  0.889
group:width                 2    0.1   0.045   0.017  0.983
group:length                2    6.0   3.024   1.125  0.327
group:device:width          2    1.6   0.823   0.306  0.737
group:device:length         2    1.7   0.858   0.319  0.727
group:width:length          2    3.1   1.531   0.570  0.567
group:device:width:length   2    8.0   4.003   1.490  0.228
Residuals                 176  473.0   2.688
```

of which `typeof() = list` and `class() = summary.aovlist`. I'm trying to use `delim.table` to help me output this table in a CSV-friendly and readable format, but the error I get says `cannot coerce class ""summary.aovlist"" to a data.frame`, despite the delim.table documentation saying it'll take a list.  I'm assuming there's something special about the aovlist subclass that's a problem here, but I'm not sure how to find out what or how to fix it.  What am I doing wrong here, and how do I output this table to a CSV in a readable way?

Answer (score -1):

What's wrong is that there is no regularity. These are not really "tables" but are a pastiche of text and matrices. To make this comma separated you would need to go through and replace all the spaces in the text output with commas, resulting I think in a mess. Furthermore, you are asking for this to be done with a function that you have not identified as to its source:

```
> ?delim.table
No documentation for ‘delim.table’ in specified packages and libraries:
you could try ‘??delim.table’
```

An instance of 'aovlist' is probably just that ... a list. You could loop through the list and output the nodes that were amenable to output as regular objects. But to show you how to do it in this case would require a great deal of guesswork.